# Orange Pi zero hardware reset

Tags: reset

I have been working on a development board for the Orange Pi Zero platform. I want to add a button which allows to restart the board. Is it possible to implement such functionality?

Comment: It looks like the only way to restart it is to interrupt its power.

Comment: Do you think it is safe to let the current flow over a normally-closed SMD button? I would rather avoid using transistors, relays or anything like this.

Comment: Do some web searching on forums where people deal with these.  Some of the schematics are out there, for some there is a SOT23 transistor on the reset net you can solder to relatively easily.

Answer (score 1):

I know with the Raspberry Pi you can use a GPIO to summon a software shutdown of the system, but afaik you cannot start up using a GPIO.
In an own application I solved this using using a tiny microprocessor that reads a button and the power of the PI and either drives the gpio to summon a clean shutdown or drives a high side mosfet to turn on the power supply to the Pi.